# Formato de ejecutable incorrecto

Tags: debian

Buenas en estos días trate de instalar una opción que permitiera multi-plataformas en mi pc debido a que algunas aplicaciones que requiero por cuestiones laborales y de estudio solo se encuentran para 64 bit y mi maquina es de 32 bits, al parecer debido a ese proceso dañe algo y ahora cuando trato de hacer cualquier cosa referente a el comando `apt-get`, este me da el siguiente error:

> bash: /usr/bin/apt-get: cannot execute binary file: Formato de
>   ejecutable incorrecto

Si me pueden decir como solventar este percance, por favor de verdad gracias

El sistema operativo que actualmente uso es Debian 9, como dije antes es de 32 bits, i386

Comment: Necesito ayuda por favor, y no quiero reintalar el sistema operativo ya que tengo mucha informacion en en mi maquina.